# How to delete cell in uiviewcontroller

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I have a ListViewController that adds a view through the method below

```
class ListViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let obj: AnObject = ObjectCollection!.getObject(index: indexPath.item)
    let cell: UICollectionViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: NSStringFromClass(UICollectionViewCell.self), for: indexPath as IndexPath)
    let cellView: UIImageView = UIImageView(image: obj.image)
    cellView.frame = cell.bounds
    cell.contentView.addSubview(cellView)

    return cell
}
```

The problem is, when I delete the content in the cell and then press the back button, the cell is not deleted and shows the previous content.

My delete method is

```
 func deleteObject(index: Int) {
        // delete from the collection
        ObjectCollection?.deleteObject(index: index)
        self.collectionView.reloadData()
    }
```

do I need to explicitly delete the cell or its contents?

Comment: Well what is `ObjectCollection`? Because obviously that isn't being saved once you delete the object from it, otherwise it wouldn't show up again when you reload your tableView

Comment: Are you sure that `ObjectCollection` is not `nil` when you call `deleteObject`?

Comment: @Losiowaty Yes I am sure it is not nil. It does remove the object from the collection since once I select it by clicking the cell it doesnt show up.

Comment: @Pierce It is being saved. The object is removed from the collection and when I select it in the cell it displays an empty object as it should. After many hours I thought that somehow the cell stays dirty and I would need to either remove or refresh it.

Comment: And how does your `numberOfItems:inSection` look like?

Comment: @Losiowaty It decreases by one as it should. When I press the back button to return to the list view is there a method of the listview controller that gets called? I could put a breakpoint and inspect the collection to see what is happening?

Comment: `viewDidAppear` should be the one you are looking for. Just to clarify one more thing - where does the `collectionView` in `deleteObject` comes from? I just realized that the deletion happens in a separate controller, am I right?

Comment: @Losiowaty Yes when I click a cell it opens a new controller whith a delete button. Clicking on the delete calls a method in the list view controller to remove the item from the collection. The collectionview in deleteobject is set in the viewDidLoad method of the listviewcontroller.

Comment: Each time when you call cellForItemAt method you create and add cellView as subview. You should add some code to manage cellView object, because your cells are reusable. Probably, it will not fix issue you are asking in this post, but it will fix some other potential issues.

Comment: @user2175783, does you use UICollectionView?

Comment: @aircraft Yes I do.

Comment: if you want change VC1's cell in VC2, you must use such as `procotol` `block` `NSNotification`, i change my answer and make a detailed description.

Answer (score 1):

It might work if you try deleteItems method.

```
    func deleteObject(indexPath: IndexPath) {
        // delete from the collection
        ObjectCollection.deleteObject(index: indexPath.row)
        self.collectionView.deleteItems(at: [indexPath])
//        self.collectionView.reloadData()
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

make sure before `reloaddata()` you must delete the cell and the cell's obj in your dataArray.

i think the method `numberOfItems:inSection`, you code is `return dataArray.count`, but you don't delete the cell's obj in the dataArray, so when you reloaddata(), your cell is still here.

Now, i know your problem, you have two VC(let's call them VC1 and VC2), you cell displayed on VC1, when you click cell , push to VC2, click VC2's delete button, you want to delete VC1's cell , am i right ?

if you want make this effort, 
you can make a `protocol` 、a property `delegate`、a protocol method such as `-(void)deleteCell` in your VC2, 
when you push to VC2, set VC1 as VC2's delegate, overwrite the protocol method in your VC1,
you click VC2's delete button, in your response method, use `[self.delegate deleteCell]`. when you go back to VC1, it will delete cell and cell's obj automatic.

Meanwhile, you also can use `NSNotification` to make the effort.

Comment: There is a `deleteObject` method right there in the question, and OP mentioned in the comments that it gets called correctly.